# NullPointerException in my Arquillian Functional test with Drone and Selenium

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, jboss-arquillian, arquillian-drone

Here is my stack-trace:

```
should_create_greeting(cn.ftc.test.BeanTest)  Time elapsed: 0.063 sec  <<< ERROR!
java.lang.RuntimeException
    at org.jboss.arquillian.drone.impl.DroneInstanceCreator.createDroneInstance(DroneInstanceCreator.java:96)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
    at org.jboss.arquillian.core.impl.ObserverImpl.invoke(ObserverImpl.java:94)
    at org.jboss.arquillian.core.impl.EventContextImpl.invokeObservers(EventContextImpl.java:99)
    at org.jboss.arquillian.core.impl.EventContextImpl.proceed(EventContextImpl.java:81)
    at org.jboss.arquillian.core.impl.ManagerImpl.fire(ManagerImpl.java:135)
    at org.jboss.arquillian.core.impl.ManagerImpl.fire(ManagerImpl.java:115)
    at org.jboss.arquillian.core.impl.EventImpl.fire(EventImpl.java:67)
    at org.jboss.arquillian.drone.impl.DroneTestEnricher.getDroneInstance(DroneTestEnricher.java:114)
    at org.jboss.arquillian.drone.impl.DroneTestEnricher.enrich(DroneTestEnricher.java:75)
    at org.jboss.arquillian.test.impl.TestInstanceEnricher.enrich(TestInstanceEnricher.java:52)
    at org.jboss.arquillian.container.test.impl.ClientTestInstanceEnricher.enrich(ClientTestInstanceEnricher.java:51)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
    at org.jboss.arquillian.core.impl.ObserverImpl.invoke(ObserverImpl.java:94)
    at org.jboss.arquillian.core.impl.EventContextImpl.invokeObservers(EventContextImpl.java:99)
    at org.jboss.arquillian.core.impl.EventContextImpl.proceed(EventContextImpl.java:81)
    at org.jboss.arquillian.container.test.impl.client.ContainerEventController.createContext(ContainerEventController.java:142)
    at org.jboss.arquillian.container.test.impl.client.ContainerEventController.createBeforeContext(ContainerEventController.java:124)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
    at org.jboss.arquillian.core.impl.ObserverImpl.invoke(ObserverImpl.java:94)
    at org.jboss.arquillian.core.impl.EventContextImpl.proceed(EventContextImpl.java:88)
    at org.jboss.arquillian.test.impl.TestContextHandler.createTestContext(TestContextHandler.java:102)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
    at org.jboss.arquillian.core.impl.ObserverImpl.invoke(ObserverImpl.java:94)
    at org.jboss.arquillian.core.impl.EventContextImpl.proceed(EventContextImpl.java:88)
    at org.jboss.arquillian.test.impl.TestContextHandler.createClassContext(TestContextHandler.java:84)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
    at org.jboss.arquillian.core.impl.ObserverImpl.invoke(ObserverImpl.java:94)
    at org.jboss.arquillian.core.impl.EventContextImpl.proceed(EventContextImpl.java:88)
    at org.jboss.arquillian.test.impl.TestContextHandler.createSuiteContext(TestContextHandler.java:65)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
    at org.jboss.arquillian.core.impl.ObserverImpl.invoke(ObserverImpl.java:94)
    at org.jboss.arquillian.core.impl.EventContextImpl.proceed(EventContextImpl.java:88)
    at org.jboss.arquillian.core.impl.ManagerImpl.fire(ManagerImpl.java:135)
    at org.jboss.arquillian.core.impl.ManagerImpl.fire(ManagerImpl.java:115)
    at org.jboss.arquillian.test.impl.EventTestRunnerAdaptor.before(EventTestRunnerAdaptor.java:95)
    at org.jboss.arquillian.junit.Arquillian$4.evaluate(Arquillian.java:222)
    at org.jboss.arquillian.junit.Arquillian.multiExecute(Arquillian.java:314)
    at org.jboss.arquillian.junit.Arquillian.access$100(Arquillian.java:46)
    at org.jboss.arquillian.junit.Arquillian$5.evaluate(Arquillian.java:240)
    at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runNotIgnored(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:79)
    at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:71)
    at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:49)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:193)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:52)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:191)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:42)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:184)
    at org.jboss.arquillian.junit.Arquillian$2.evaluate(Arquillian.java:185)
    at org.jboss.arquillian.junit.Arquillian.multiExecute(Arquillian.java:314)
    at org.jboss.arquillian.junit.Arquillian.access$100(Arquillian.java:46)
    at org.jboss.arquillian.junit.Arquillian$3.evaluate(Arquillian.java:199)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:236)
    at org.jboss.arquillian.junit.Arquillian.run(Arquillian.java:147)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.junit4.JUnit4Provider.execute(JUnit4Provider.java:252)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.junit4.JUnit4Provider.executeTestSet(JUnit4Provider.java:141)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.junit4.JUnit4Provider.invoke(JUnit4Provider.java:112)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.util.ReflectionUtils.invokeMethodWithArray(ReflectionUtils.java:189)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.ProviderFactory$ProviderProxy.invoke(ProviderFactory.java:165)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.ProviderFactory.invokeProvider(ProviderFactory.java:85)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.ForkedBooter.runSuitesInProcess(ForkedBooter.java:115)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.ForkedBooter.main(ForkedBooter.java:75)
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.jboss.arquillian.drone.webdriver.factory.WebDriverFactory.createInstance(WebDriverFactory.java:124)
    at org.jboss.arquillian.drone.webdriver.factory.WebDriverFactory.createInstance(WebDriverFactory.java:41)
    at org.jboss.arquillian.drone.impl.DroneCallableCreator$1.call(DroneCallableCreator.java:89)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:303)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:138)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.runTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:895)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:918)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:662)

cn.ftc.test.BeanTest  Time elapsed: 0.196 sec  <<< ERROR!
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Unexpected callable present in Drone Context, should be already instantiated at this moment.
    at org.jboss.arquillian.drone.impl.InstanceOrCallableInstanceImpl.asInstance(InstanceOrCallableInstanceImpl.java:57)
    at org.jboss.arquillian.drone.impl.DroneEnhancer.deenhanceDrone(DroneEnhancer.java:119)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
    at org.jboss.arquillian.core.impl.ObserverImpl.invoke(ObserverImpl.java:94)
    at org.jboss.arquillian.core.impl.EventContextImpl.invokeObservers(EventContextImpl.java:99)
    at org.jboss.arquillian.core.impl.EventContextImpl.proceed(EventContextImpl.java:81)
    at org.jboss.arquillian.core.impl.ManagerImpl.fire(ManagerImpl.java:135)
    at org.jboss.arquillian.core.impl.ManagerImpl.fire(ManagerImpl.java:115)
    at org.jboss.arquillian.core.impl.EventImpl.fire(EventImpl.java:67)
    at org.jboss.arquillian.drone.impl.DroneDestructor.destroyClassScopedDrone(DroneDestructor.java:93)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
    at org.jboss.arquillian.core.impl.ObserverImpl.invoke(ObserverImpl.java:94)
    at org.jboss.arquillian.core.impl.EventContextImpl.invokeObservers(EventContextImpl.java:99)
    at org.jboss.arquillian.core.impl.EventContextImpl.proceed(EventContextImpl.java:81)
    at org.jboss.arquillian.test.impl.TestContextHandler.createClassContext(TestContextHandler.java:84)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
    at org.jboss.arquillian.core.impl.ObserverImpl.invoke(ObserverImpl.java:94)
    at org.jboss.arquillian.core.impl.EventContextImpl.proceed(EventContextImpl.java:88)
    at org.jboss.arquillian.test.impl.TestContextHandler.createSuiteContext(TestContextHandler.java:65)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
    at org.jboss.arquillian.core.impl.ObserverImpl.invoke(ObserverImpl.java:94)
    at org.jboss.arquillian.core.impl.EventContextImpl.proceed(EventContextImpl.java:88)
    at org.jboss.arquillian.core.impl.ManagerImpl.fire(ManagerImpl.java:135)
    at org.jboss.arquillian.core.impl.ManagerImpl.fire(ManagerImpl.java:115)
    at org.jboss.arquillian.test.impl.EventTestRunnerAdaptor.afterClass(EventTestRunnerAdaptor.java:87)
    at org.jboss.arquillian.junit.Arquillian$3$1.evaluate(Arquillian.java:204)
    at org.jboss.arquillian.junit.Arquillian.multiExecute(Arquillian.java:314)
    at org.jboss.arquillian.junit.Arquillian.access$100(Arquillian.java:46)
    at org.jboss.arquillian.junit.Arquillian$3.evaluate(Arquillian.java:199)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:236)
    at org.jboss.arquillian.junit.Arquillian.run(Arquillian.java:147)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.junit4.JUnit4Provider.execute(JUnit4Provider.java:252)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.junit4.JUnit4Provider.executeTestSet(JUnit4Provider.java:141)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.junit4.JUnit4Provider.invoke(JUnit4Provider.java:112)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.util.ReflectionUtils.invokeMethodWithArray(ReflectionUtils.java:189)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.ProviderFactory$ProviderProxy.invoke(ProviderFactory.java:165)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.ProviderFactory.invokeProvider(ProviderFactory.java:85)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.ForkedBooter.runSuitesInProcess(ForkedBooter.java:115)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.ForkedBooter.main(ForkedBooter.java:75)


Results :

Tests in error: 
  should_create_greeting(cn.ftc.test.BeanTest)
  cn.ftc.test.BeanTest: Unexpected callable present in Drone Context, should be already instantiated at this moment.

Tests run: 2, Failures: 0, Errors: 2, Skipped: 0
```

And here is my test class:

```
@RunWith(Arquillian.class)
public class BeanTest {

    @Deployment(testable = false)
    public static WebArchive createDeployment() {
        WebArchive war = ShrinkWrap.create(WebArchive.class, "test.war")
                .addClass(Bean.class)
                               .addAsWebInfResource(EmptyAsset.INSTANCE, "beans.xml");
        System.out.println(war.toString(true));
        return war;
    }

    @Inject
    Bean bean;

    @Drone
    WebDriver webdriver;

    @Test
    public void should_create_greeting() {
        Assert.assertNotNull(webdriver);

    }
}
```

`dependencyManagement`:

```
<dependencyManagement>


        <dependencies>

            <!-- arquillian and Drone -->
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.jboss.arquillian</groupId>
                <artifactId>arquillian-bom</artifactId>
                <version>1.1.3.Final</version>
                <type>pom</type>
                <scope>import</scope>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.jboss.arquillian.extension</groupId>
                <artifactId>arquillian-drone-bom</artifactId>
                <version>1.2.3.Final</version>
                <type>pom</type>
                <scope>import</scope>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.jboss.arquillian.selenium</groupId>
                <artifactId>selenium-bom</artifactId>
                <version>2.35.0</version>
                <type>pom</type>
                <scope>import</scope>
            </dependency>
... ...
```

`dependency`:

```
<dependency>
            <groupId>org.jboss.arquillian.graphene</groupId>
            <artifactId>graphene-webdriver</artifactId>
            <version>2.0.1.Final</version>
            <type>pom</type>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
```

arquillian.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<arquillian xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns="http://jboss.org/schema/arquillian"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://jboss.org/schema/arquillian http://jboss.org/schema/arquillian/arquillian_1_0.xsd">

    <extension qualifier="webdriver">
        <property name="browser">firefox</property>
    </extension>


</arquillian>
```

I have no idea about how the `NullPointerException` comes into being. It's weird!

Comment: Looks to me like you just found a bug in arquillian...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is caused by a reverted change in 1.1.3 that was introduced in 1.0.4. The new model introduced in 1.0.4 had too many other bad side effects and somewhere along the way Drone got dependent on how it works. :)

https://issues.jboss.org/browse/ARQ-1653

Answer (score 0):

Fixed. I changed the dependency from `org.jboss.arquillian:arquillian-bom:1.1.3.Final` to `org.jboss.arquillian:arquillian-bom:1.1.2.Final`, Then it works!!!!!

Comment: Had the same problem. I quickly went through the versions: 1.1.2 works, 1.1.3, 1.1.4 and 1.1.5 fail